# Custom usernames using Google play game services

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-cloud-storage

I am using GPGS in my game for multiplayer and cloud storage and was wondering if there was a way to access the data from other users that store data using cloud storage?

Essentially, I want each user to pick a username in game that saves to the cloud, but I need to make sure that no one else has that name before it saves. So I figured I could loop through all the users and check their saved data for their username but I have not figured out how to access another users data. If this is not possible then are there any suggestions? Should I use something like google app engine to store all the usernames and use that file to compare all the new usernames to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google cloud storage is not a replacement for database. It's a great service to store objects in the cloud.

In your case I would look at both option to store your users' data:

- https://cloud.google.com/datastore/ - A NoSQL database that will work great both from Google app engine and Google compute engine. Depend on your technology stack and needs.
- https://cloud.google.com/sql/ - A (my)SQL solution in the cloud. If you worked with MySQL in the past, it will be very easy for you to use it. Almost everything will work the same.

Btw, in the specific case of a new user you could send after the first failure 3-5 suggestions to the users of 'free names' that you know are not in the system. This way, you will improve their experience.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I'm looking at Google datastore and it seems a bit more complex/overwhelming than I thought. Do you know of any tutorials that focuses on saving data to Google datastore?